# No such table as django_site

Tags: django, django-admin, django-settings

I am following from the docs of [django-disqus](http://django-disqus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#configuring-your-django-installation) to use it in my project. I have installed it in my settings, with other needed settings (`API key` and `short name`). But when I try to run these commands:

```
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> Site.objects.all()
```

I am getting an error:

> OperationalError: no such table: django_site

I have already installed `django.contrib.admin` in my settings and is using it in my project. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Make sure you have added `'django.contrib.sites'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`, then run `migrate` to create the required table.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I'm still having one problem though. When I visit the page, its giving me this error: `You're using the Django "sites framework" without having set the SITE_ID setting`. Where do I add the SITE_ID? Please help me.

Comment: In your settings.py.see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework)  for full instructions.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm getting this error with `manage.py test`, even though I have `django.contrib.sites` in my `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: @Cerin that sounds like an unrelated issue. Since you are running the tests, the table is probably missing from the test database in your case.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is working only if I do the migration before starting using the Site app. 
I have to remove all the imports in the code then makemigration/migrate. 
After that I start using the Site app.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue because I had an `exit(1)` (error code) in a migration of mine. All migrations were not run, that was the hint.